# Trying to add lists to my collections (form_for, routing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, crud, form-for, nested

Hey guys I am trying to be able to add lists to my collections. I am new to rails any help would be appreciated. Currently I am trying to build a form to make a new list, but the new/create actions seem to be messed up.

The lists will end up living in the collections show view later via ajax.

Ultimately the goal is for each user to own multiple collections and in each collection there will be multiple lists, in each lists multiple items.

Collections

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @collection = Collection.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

def new
    @collection = Collection.new
end

def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
    @list = List.all
end

def create
    @collection = Collection.new(collection_params)
    @collection.user_id = current_user.id
    # render :text => CGI.escapeHTML(@collection.inspect)
    if @collection.save
        redirect_to root_path(@user)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    if @collection.update(collection_params)
        redirect_to root_path(@user)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @collection.destroy
    redirect_to root_path(@user)
end

private
  def collection_params
    params.require(:collection).permit(:alias, :notes, :visibility)
  end
  def find_collection
    @collection = @user.collection.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Lists

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @list = List.all
end

def new
    @list = List.new
end

def create
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
    @list =
    @collection.lists.create(comments_params)
    if @collection.lists.save
    redirect_to root_path(@user)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
end
```

Users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @collection = Collection.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @user.collection = Collection.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    # render :text => CGI.escapeHTML(@collection.inspect)
end
end
```

The link I was trying

```
<%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i> Add Subcategory'.html_safe, new_collection_list_path(@collection.id)  %>
```

Current routes

```
devise_scope :user do
authenticated :user do
  root 'collections#index', as: :authenticated
   resources :collections do
    resources :lists
  end
end
```

Failed form_for

```
<%= form_for([@collection, @collection.lists.build]) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

Models

```
Users has_many :collections


Collections belong_to :user
has_many :lists


Lists belong_to :collection
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ListsController new and create actions to the following:

```
def new
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
end

def create
  @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
  @list = @collection.lists.build(params[:list])
  if @list.save
    redirect_to root_path(@user)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: After changing it, I still get undefined method for 'lists'. Using <%= form_for([@collection, @collection.lists.build]) do |f| %> in the new.html.erb. I should mention in the db, collections reference users, and lists reference collections. If that matters

Comment: Are you sure you have the line 'has_many :lists' in your Collection model?

Comment: AH! Thank you so much, now I get the error 'unknown attribute: collection_id' but I feel a million times closer.

Comment: You need to have collection_id field in the 'lists' table.

Comment: ah it was plural, thanks man I have been staring at this all day. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey I was wondering how I would nest the next resource? So Collections have_many lists and lists have_many links. I have a loop, <% (at)collection.lists.each do |list| %> and inside the loop I want to then loop through all the links of each list but <% (at)collection.lists.links.each do %> and or <% (at)list.links.each do %> def don't work, What should I be looking into? My gut says I suck at ORM. (at) == @ stack wouldnt let me send with them in there.